# Pointers address location

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

As part of our training in the Academy of Programming Languages, we also learned C. During the test, we encountered the question of what the program output would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "hmmmm..";
    const char * const ptr1[] = {"to be","or not to be","that is the question"};
    char *ptr2 = "that is the qusetion";

    (&ptr2)[3] = str;

    strcpy(str,"(Hamlet)");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ptr1)/sizeof(*ptr1); ++i){
        printf("%s ", ptr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Later, after examining the answers, it became clear that the cell (& ptr2)[3] was identical to the memory cell in &ptr1[2], so the output of the program is: `to be or not to be (Hamlet)`

My question is, is it possible to know, only by written code in the notebook, without checking any compiler, that a certain pointer (or all variables in general) follow or precede other variables in memory?

Note, I do not mean array variables, so all the elements in the array must be in sequence.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is: "The output of this program is undetermined because it invokes undefined behaviour."

Comment: @Jabberwocky Except if the exact environment is specified

Comment: @Ctx maybe, but the OP didn't mention anything

Comment: Well, is it `undefined behavior` or is it implementation-defined? If the former, all bets are really off. If the latter, you can predict something.

Comment: Nice "Typo" by the way, in the second "question". I presume that was part of the original code?

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(str,"(Hamlet)");`   results in the compiler outputting the message: `untitled.c:11:5: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 9 bytes into a region of size 8 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]`   I.E. the statement overflows the upper bounds of the array `str[]`  This is undefined behavior.  With undefined behavior, anything can happen, including the code seeming to work

Answer (score 8):

In this statement:

```
(&ptr2)[3] = str;
```

`ptr2` was defined with `char *ptr2` inside `main`. With this definition, the compiler is responsible for providing storage for `ptr2`. The compiler is allowed to use whatever storage it wants for this—it could be before `ptr1`, it could be after `ptr1`, it could be close, it could be far away.

Then `&ptr2` takes the address of `ptr2`. This is allowed, but we do not know where that address will be in relation to `ptr1` or anything else, because the compiler is allowed to use whatever storage it wants.

Since `ptr2` is a `char *`, `&ptr2` is a pointer to `char *`, also known as `char **`.

Then `(&ptr2)[3]` attempts to refer to element 3 of an array of `char *` that is at `&ptr2`. But there is no array there in C’s model of computation. There is just one `char *` there. When you try to refer to element of 3 of an array when there is no element 3 of an array, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Thus, this code is a bad example. It appears the test author misunderstood C, and this code does not illustrate what was intended.

Comment: The test author probably want to see whether students know those pointers are pushed on to stack, assuming the variables are pushed in the same order coded.

Comment: Many thanks for the superb explanation.
I checked the test again now, no work environment was specified.
However, I checked this code on GCC compiler on Linux Ubuntu, and here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler too, and it turned out that the answer in both of them had come out the same, in accordance with the examiner's expectations.
Pure luck?

Comment: @JavaStarter No, it's simply the common way how this is handled, but there are (real-world) conditions, which aren't even particularly rare, where this will fail.

Comment: @JavaStarter: It is not entirely luck in the sense that compilers are written in sensible ways. Typically a person who writes the code to allocate space for local variables is just going to do something straightforward to start with, and that might be to allocate in whatever order the variables are found in source code. But then it gets complicated. To satisfy alignment requirements, some variables must be allocated on certain memory boundaries. If you do that in the order variables are found in source code it will waste space. So a smarter compiler writer writes code to rearrange the…

Comment: … allocations in a more space-efficient way. Then they are no longer in the same order as the source code. On top of that, the compiler will include an optimizer which may go and transform the code in various ways to improve it, and those transformations might eliminate local variables, or combine them, or rearrange them. Due to these effects and others, you might sometimes see variables with neighboring declarations have neighboring addresses in simple routines, but, in larger routines, the likelihood things get rearranged grows. Regardless, you can never rely on where an object will be.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible and no such assumptions can be made.

By writing outside a variable's space, this code invokes undefined behavior, it's basically "illegal" and anything can happen when you run it. The C language specification says nothing about variables being allocated on a stack in some particular order that you can exploit, it does however say that accessing random memory is undefined behavior.

Basically this code is pretty horrible and should never be used, even less so in a teaching environment. It makes me sad, how people mis-understand C and still teach it to others. :/

Comment: If you have to rant, then at least specify what's wrong with the code.

Comment: @Ctx Good point, I toned it down and tried to be a bit more informative. Thanks.

Comment: I so agree with this, this ”teacher” should not be teaching about C.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *ptr2 = some initializer;

(&ptr2)[3] = str;
```

When you evaluate &ptr2, you obtain the address of memory where is stored the pointer that points to that initializer.

When you do `(&ptr2)[3]=something` you try to write `3*sizeof(void*)` locations further from the location of ptr2, the address of a string.  This is invalid and almost sure it finishes with segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

A program usually is loaded in memory with this structure: 
Stack, Mmap'ed files, Heap, BSS (uninitialized static variables), Data segment (Initialized static variables) and Text (Compiled code)

You can learn more here:
https://manybutfinite.com/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/

Depending on how you declare the variable it will go to one of the places said before.

The compiler will arrange the BSS and Data segment variables as he wishes on compilation time so usually no chance. Neither heap vars (the OS will get the memory block that fits better the space allocated)

In the stack (which is a LIFO structure) the variables are put one over eachother so if you have:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
```

You can say that a and b will be placed one following the other. So, in this case you can tell.

There is another exception and that is if the variable is an structure or an array, they are always placed like i said before, each one following the last.

In your code ptr1 is an array of arrays of chars so it will follow the exception i said.

In fact, do the following exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    const char * const ptr1[] = {"to be","or not to be","that is the question"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ptr1[i]); j++) 
            printf("%p -> %c\n", &ptr1[i][j], ptr1[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

and you will see the memory address and its content!

Have a nice day.

Comment: Re “In the stack (which is a LIFO structure) the variables are put one over each other so if you have:… You can say that a and b will be placed one following the other. So, in this case you can tell.”: No, you cannot. There is no guarantee that variables are put on the stack in the same order they appear in source code.